# How pass to a same view more than one variable in different function - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function form($id)
{
    $teacher = Teacher::find($id);
    return view('test.form_test')withTeacher($teacher);
}

public function seachQuestion()
{
    $questions = Question::all();
    return view('test.form_test')->with('questions',$question);
}
```

The function seachQuestion is called from a button in the View.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the variables as an array

```
return view('test.form_test')->with(['questions' => $question, 'answers' => $answers, ...]);
```

But, be careful in using the variables inside the view. Cuz, it could populate the `undefined variable` ERROR if you wouldn't care of the using them properly.

Comment: @HenriqueFerreira, you're welcome. If it helped you and you found the answer, you can select it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a self-aware array to the view:

```
return view('test.form_test')->with('data' => array('varName' => 'questions', 'varValues' => $questions));
```

and:

```
return view('test.form_test')->with('data' => array('varName' => 'teachers', 'varValues' => $teachers));
```

and you use it inside view like this:

```
<h1>{{$data['varName']}}</h1>
<p>
   @foreach($data['varValues'] as $value)
     <strong>{{$value}}</strong>
     <br>
   @endforeach
</p>
```